# How to retrieve the url of created github repo with the gh command?

Tags: git, github

How to retrieve the url of created github repo with the gh command? I mean I created the repo with gh command and what if I don't want to go to the github. is it possible to retrieve its url not going to the github?

I did git repo create "name_of_the_repo". Don't now how to work with it futherly with th command promt. Please advice.

Comment: To get nothing but the URL: `gh repo view --json url --jq '.url'`

Answer (score 1):

```
gh repo view owner/repo --json url --jq '.url'
```

Breakdown:

- `gh repo view owner/repo` will display the description and the README of `owner/repo`. (If you are currently in a repo, then using only `gh repo view` will imply you want to view that repo.)
- `--json url` will output JSON with the `url` field

  ```js
  {
    "url": "https://github.com/squidfunk/mkdocs-material"
  }
  ```
- `--jq '.url` will filter that JSON output using a [jq](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/) expression

You can also use `gh repo view owner/repo --web` to open it on the web.

See the documentation for [`gh repo view`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo_view).

Answer (score 0):

Try `gh repo view <your repo name>`

Alternatively, you can see the list of repos using the command
`gh repo list`

Answer (score -1):

`git config --get remote.origin.url`

Git show remote url-How can I determine the URL that a local Git repository was originally cloned from? - Intellipaat Community - https://intellipaat.com/community/3102/git-show-remote-url-how-can-i-determine-the-url-that-a-local-git-repository-was-originally-cloned-from